# How to move widget with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to this. 
On my website, I have been trying to fix the mobile version of it.

[https://glacieradventure.is/tour/vatnajokull-glacier-walk](https://glacieradventure.is/tour/vatnajokull-glacier-walk/)/

If you look at this page on PC you will see the booking widget on the right side but when you switch it to mobile device view the booking widget goes to the bottom. 
I want the booking widget under `<h2>`.

[image: Like this]
I did this by moving the html code, but it does not work with the css, and when I switch back to PC view it looks wrong.

Please help a girl out!

Comment: Are you using some CSS framework here? And please share the code of that particular component so that we can understand it better.

Comment: This is not possible with the current structure. You need to put `<aside>` below `<h2>` and then play with `CSS`. Also, use `flex` layout.

Answer (score 0):

After `h2` tag, create a `div` element 
**ie,**

```
<div class="responsive-only">{Copy and past the booking widget code here}</div>
```

// Note: So the booking widget code present in both places.

```
<style>
.responsive-only {display: none;}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.responsive-only {display: block;}
// Note: Then hide the another one widget (which appears in the bottom)
}
</style>
```

Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add styles `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` to your element with the class `.twocolumns` at your mobile version. It should help you.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .twocolumns {
    padding-right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```